# How to Integrate Amazon API Gateway with EKS using Application Load Balancer (ALB)?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, load-balance, eks

According to the [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/integrate-amazon-api-gateway-with-amazon-eks/), it is possible to integrate Amazon API Gateway with EKS using ALB. However, by far most of this documentation explains how to do this with NLB instead of ALB. So hopefully, someone can explain how to do this with ALB.

For example, do I need to create ingress to enable me calling my services? Or is there another way?  How to configure my ALB and my API gateway?

Answer (score 1):

From the same page:

```
The steps to integrate ALB and NLB with API Gateway are identical.
```

Which is followed by a sentence with a link to a documentation for an [ALB ingress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html), including prerequisites for VPC subnets and EKS resources.

Yes, you have to create one unless you'd want to configure ALB manually instead of using `Ingress` manifests inside k8s.